# Reader XML Google Earth not working C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, google-earth

I have a code in my C # that is working to read nodes from an XML file. But with the XML below I'm not getting read data. This is an XML export Google Earth
I've tried everything and I can not make it work ...

What am I doing wrong?

code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    var xml = client.DownloadString(Server.MapPath("doc.xml"));
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);

    foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("Folder"))
    {
        string teste = node.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
        foreach (XmlNode node1 in node.SelectNodes("Placemark"))
        {
            string teste1 = node.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

This code I alter:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("kml/Document/Folder"))
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("Document/Folder"))
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("kml"))
```

and not working.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>Clientes</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <LookAt>
        <longitude>-49.0749402778</longitude>
        <latitude>-26.986807651</latitude>
        <altitude>0</altitude>
        <heading>0</heading>
        <tilt>0</tilt>
        <range>219018.609535</range>
    </LookAt>
    <Style id="pground_fresnel">
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>66ff00ff</color>
            <outline>0</outline>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Folder>
        <name>Sites</name>
        <Placemark id="site_174196976">
            <name>ERB - FTZA</name>
            <description><![CDATA[<p>Approximate profiles to nearby sites</p>


                         <ul>
                            <li>Profile between ERB - FTZA and <a href="#site_174641424">EFA - ST01 - Gilmar Salvador</a><br>
                            <img src="http://profile.heywhatsthat.com/bin/profile.cgi?src=MTPTP&metric=1&axes=1&curvature=1&pt1=-26.8616181581%2C-49.0435799235%2C%2C%2C&pt0=-26.8616887564%2C-49.0433335127%2C%2C%2C">
                            </li>
                         </ul>


                         <ul>
                            <li>Profile between ERB - FTZA and <a href="#site_174558608">EFA - PTP - VALMOR Têxtil</a><br>
                            <img src="http://profile.heywhatsthat.com/bin/profile.cgi?src=MTPTP&metric=1&axes=1&curvature=1&pt1=-26.8621335079%2C-49.0440949031%2C%2C%2C&pt0=-26.8616887564%2C-49.0433335127%2C%2C%2C">
                            </li>
                         </ul>


                         <ul>
                            <li>Profile between ERB - FTZA and <a href="#site_174686480">EFA - ST01 - Jussara Marcelino</a><br>
                            <img src="http://profile.heywhatsthat.com/bin/profile.cgi?src=MTPTP&metric=1&axes=1&curvature=1&pt1=-26.8608348824%2C-49.0445371763%2C%2C%2C&pt0=-26.8616887564%2C-49.0433335127%2C%2C%2C">
                            </li>
                         </ul>


                         <ul>
                            <li>Profile between ERB - FTZA and <a href="#site_174558064">EFA - ST01 - Fabricio Dalcenter</a><br>
                            <img src="http://profile.heywhatsthat.com/bin/profile.cgi?src=MTPTP&metric=1&axes=1&curvature=1&pt1=-26.8602120003%2C-49.0431030006%2C%2C%2C&pt0=-26.8616887564%2C-49.0433335127%2C%2C%2C">
                            </li>
                         </ul>


                         <ul>
                            <li>Profile between ERB - FTZA and <a href="#site_174686928">MCO - PTP - Celpa Defumados</a><br>
                            <img src="http://profile.heywhatsthat.com/bin/profile.cgi?src=MTPTP&metric=1&axes=1&curvature=1&pt1=-26.8582398311%2C-49.0353971392%2C%2C%2C&pt0=-26.8616887564%2C-49.0433335127%2C%2C%2C">
                            </li>
                         </ul>


                         <ul>
                            <li>Profile between ERB - FTZA and <a href="#site_114087920">MCO - PTP - Ananda Têxtil</a><br>
                            <img src="http://profile.heywhatsthat.com/bin/profile.cgi?src=MTPTP&metric=1&axes=1&curvature=1&pt1=-26.8569743348%2C-49.0334629119%2C%2C%2C&pt0=-26.8616887564%2C-49.0433335127%2C%2C%2C">
                            </li>
                         </ul>


                         <ul>
                            <li>Profile between ERB - FTZA and <a href="#site_174555568">Prédios Tribess</a><br>
                            <img src="http://profile.heywhatsthat.com/bin/profile.cgi?src=MTPTP&metric=1&axes=1&curvature=1&pt1=-26.8705460688%2C-49.0501338292%2C%2C%2C&pt0=-26.8616887564%2C-49.0433335127%2C%2C%2C">
                            </li>
                         </ul>


                         <ul>
                            <li>Profile between ERB - FTZA and <a href="#site_114081584">Rede Top Tribess</a><br>
                            <img src="http://profile.heywhatsthat.com/bin/profile.cgi?src=MTPTP&metric=1&axes=1&curvature=1&pt1=-26.8754375344%2C-49.0547021027%2C%2C%2C&pt0=-26.8616887564%2C-49.0433335127%2C%2C%2C">
                            </li>
                         </ul>


                         <ul>
                            <li>Profile between ERB - FTZA and <a href="#site_174690128">Estudo maion</a><br>
                            <img src="http://profile.heywhatsthat.com/bin/profile.cgi?src=MTPTP&metric=1&axes=1&curvature=1&pt1=-26.8711031328%2C-49.0686806897%2C%2C%2C&pt0=-26.8616887564%2C-49.0433335127%2C%2C%2C">
                            </li>
                         </ul>


                         <ul>
                            <li>Profile between ERB - FTZA and <a href="#site_114080784">Mafisa</a><br>
                            <img src="http://profile.heywhatsthat.com/bin/profile.cgi?src=MTPTP&metric=1&axes=1&curvature=1&pt1=-26.8625412632%2C-49.0864785295%2C%2C%2C&pt0=-26.8616887564%2C-49.0433335127%2C%2C%2C">
                            </li>
                         </ul>


            <em>
                Profile images are Copyright 2008 Michael Kosowsky.
                All rights reserved. Used with permission. For more
                information, visit
                <a href="http://www.heywhatsthat.com/">HeyWhatsThat</a>
                </em>]]></description>
            <styleUrl>#msn_donut</styleUrl>
            <Point>
                <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
                <coordinates>-49.0433335127,-26.8616887564,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Folder>
    <Folder>
        <name>Links</name>
        <Folder>
            <name>ERB Gasparinho - ST01 - MPO to EGO - LAN - Jurema</name>
            <LookAt>
                <longitude>-48.9692241831</longitude>
                <latitude>-26.9532849988</latitude>
                <altitude>0</altitude>
                <heading>-0.8219678042850001</heading>
                <tilt>68</tilt>
                <range>18.4258281664</range>
            </LookAt>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Vertical Fresnel</name>
                <LookAt>
                    <longitude>-48.9692241831</longitude>
                    <latitude>-26.9532849988</latitude>
                    <altitude>0</altitude>
                    <heading>-0.8219678042850001</heading>
                    <tilt>68</tilt>
                    <range>18.4258281664</range>
                </LookAt>
                <styleUrl>#pvertical_fresnel</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                -48.969316956,-26.9532861916,76.299996104 -48.9693166688,-26.95328618790001,76.26002066620001 -48.9693158091,-26.9532861769,76.2002543831 -48.9693143821,-26.9532861585,76.12106573360001 -48.9693123968,-26.953286133,76.0229429422 -48.96930986530001,-26.9532861004,75.9064909685 -48.9693068032,-26.9532860611,75.7724277776 -48.9693032295,-26.9532860151,75.6215799136 -48.96929916610001,-26.9532859629,75.4548774039 -48.9692946381,-26.9532859047,75.2733480248 -48.9692896734,-26.9532858408,75.0781109653 -48.9692843027,-26.9532857718,74.8703699268 -48.9692785589,-26.9532856979,74.6514057018 -48.9692724777,-26.9532856197,74.4225682778 -48.9692660964,-26.9532855377,74.1852685134 -48.96925945440001,-26.95328545230001,73.9409694406 -48.9692525926,-26.9532853641,73.6911772444 -48.9692455533,-26.9532852736,73.4374319769 -48.96923838,-26.9532851813,73.18129806189999 -48.9692311169,-26.9532850879,72.9243546502 -48.96922380870001,-26.953284994,72.6681858834 -48.9692165005,-26.9532849,72.414371127 -48.9692092374,-26.9532848066,72.1644752336 -48.9692020642,-26.9532847144,71.92003889439999 -48.96919502500001,-26.9532846239,71.6825691406 -48.9691881632,-26.9532845356,71.4535300524 -48.9691815213,-26.9532844502,71.23433373170001 -48.96917514,-26.9532843682,71.02633159689999 -48.9691690588,-26.95328429,70.8308060502 -48.9691633152,-26.9532842161,70.6489625718 -48.9691579446,-26.9532841471,70.481922287 -48.96915298,-26.9532840833,70.3307150548 -48.96914845210001,-26.953284025,70.1962731181 -48.9691443888,-26.9532839728,70.079425356 -48.96914081520001,-26.9532839268,69.98089217400001 -48.9691377533,-26.9532838875,69.90128106189999 -48.9691352219,-26.9532838549,69.84108284849999 -48.9691332367,-26.9532838294,69.800668676 -48.9691318099,-26.953283811,69.7802877112 -48.96913095039999,-26.9532838,69.7800656094 -48.9691306633,-26.9532837963,69.79999610430001 -48.9691306633,-26.9532837963,69.80000389600001 -48.96913095039999,-26.9532838,69.8399666219 -48.9691318099,-26.953283811,69.8997279071 -48.9691332367,-26.9532838294,69.97891166780001 -48.9691352219,-26.9532838549,70.0770297098 -48.9691377533,-26.9532838875,70.1934771027 -48.96914081520001,-26.9532839268,70.3275359097 -48.9691443888,-26.9532839728,70.4783796135 -48.96914845210001,-26.953284025,70.6450782127 -48.96915298,-26.9532840833,70.82660395489999 -48.9691579446,-26.9532841471,71.0218376736 -48.9691633152,-26.9532842161,71.2295756879 -48.9691690588,-26.95328429,71.4485372239 -48.96917514,-26.9532843682,71.677372311 -48.9691815213,-26.9532844502,71.91467010469999 -48.9691881632,-26.9532845356,72.1589675852 -48.96919502500001,-26.9532846239,72.40875857739999 -48.9692020642,-26.9532847144,72.6625030366 -48.9692092374,-26.9532848066,72.91863654390001 -48.9692165005,-26.9532849,73.17557995110001 -48.96922380870001,-26.953284994,73.4317491166 -48.9692311169,-26.9532850879,73.68556467240001 -48.96923838,-26.9532851813,73.9354617611 -48.9692455533,-26.9532852736,74.17989968409999 -48.9692525926,-26.9532853641,74.4173714002 -48.96925945440001,-26.95328545230001,74.64641281750001 -48.9692660964,-26.9532855377,74.8656118194 -48.9692724777,-26.9532856197,75.0736169711 -48.9692785589,-26.9532856979,75.26914585180001 -48.9692843027,-26.9532857718,75.45099296079999 -48.9692896734,-26.9532858408,75.6180371503 -48.9692946381,-26.9532859047,75.7692485373 -48.96929916610001,-26.9532859629,75.9036948533 -48.9693032295,-26.9532860151,76.020547192 -48.9693068032,-26.9532860611,76.11908511999999 -48.96930986530001,-26.9532861004,76.1987011181 -48.9693123968,-26.953286133,76.2589043273 -48.9693143821,-26.9532861585,76.2993235747 -48.9693158091,-26.9532861769,76.3197096622 -48.9693166688,-26.95328618790001,76.3199369029 -48.969316956,-26.9532861916,76.3000038957 
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Ground Fresnel</name>
                <LookAt>
                    <longitude>-48.9692241831</longitude>
                    <latitude>-26.9532849988</latitude>
                    <altitude>0</altitude>
                    <heading>-0.8219678042850001</heading>
                    <tilt>68</tilt>
                    <range>18.4258281664</range>
                </LookAt>
                <styleUrl>#ground_fresnel</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                -48.969316956,-26.9532861916,0 -48.9693166731,-26.9532859176,0 -48.96931581770001,-26.9532856379,0 -48.969314395,-26.9532853542,0 -48.9693124139,-26.9532850683,0 -48.96930988639999,-26.953284782,0 -48.9693068283,-26.9532844969,0 -48.9693032583,-26.953284215,0 -48.96929919850001,-26.9532839378,0 -48.9692946739,-26.9532836671,0 -48.96928971240001,-26.9532834046,0 -48.9692843446,-26.953283152,0 -48.9692786036,-26.9532829106,0 -48.9692725247,-26.9532826822,0 -48.9692661455,-26.9532824679,0 -48.9692595053,-26.9532822693,0 -48.96925264499999,-26.9532820874,0 -48.969245607,-26.9532819235,0 -48.9692384345,-26.9532817785,0 -48.96923117189999,-26.9532816533,0 -48.9692238639,-26.9532815487,0 -48.9692165555,-26.9532814654,0 -48.9692092919,-26.9532814038,0 -48.9692021178,-26.9532813643,0 -48.96919507740001,-26.9532813473,0 -48.9691882142,-26.9532813527,0 -48.96918157040001,-26.9532813805,0 -48.969175187,-26.9532814307,0 -48.96916910350001,-26.9532815028,0 -48.9691633572,-26.9532815964,0 -48.96915798359999,-26.953281711,0 -48.9691530158,-26.9532818458,0 -48.96914848450001,-26.953282,0 -48.9691444177,-26.9532821727,0 -48.96914084029999,-26.9532823628,0 -48.9691377744,-26.9532825691,0 -48.969135239,-26.9532827903,0 -48.9691332496,-26.9532830251,0 -48.9691318186,-26.9532832721,0 -48.9691309547,-26.9532835297,0 -48.9691306633,-26.9532837963,0 -48.9691306633,-26.9532837963,0 -48.96913094599999,-26.9532840703,0 -48.96913180129999,-26.95328435,0 -48.96913322380001,-26.9532846336,0 -48.9691352049,-26.9532849195,0 -48.9691377322,-26.9532852059,0 -48.9691407902,-26.9532854909,0 -48.96914435999999,-26.9532857729,0 -48.96914841970001,-26.9532860501,0 -48.9691529442,-26.9532863207,0 -48.9691579056,-26.9532865832,0 -48.96916327330001,-26.9532868359,0 -48.9691690142,-26.9532870772,0 -48.969175093,-26.9532873057,0 -48.9691814721,-26.95328752,0 -48.9691881123,-26.9532877186,0 -48.9691949725,-26.9532879005,0 -48.9692020105,-26.9532880644,0 -48.969209183,-26.9532882094,0 -48.9692164456,-26.9532883346,0 -48.9692237536,-26.9532884392,0 -48.9692310619,-26.9532885226,0 -48.9692383255,-26.9532885842,0 -48.9692454997,-26.9532886236,0 -48.9692525401,-26.9532886407,0 -48.9692594034,-26.9532886353,0 -48.9692660472,-26.9532886074,0 -48.9692724307,-26.9532885573,0 -48.96927851430001,-26.9532884852,0 -48.9692842607,-26.9532883916,0 -48.9692896344,-26.953288277,0 -48.96929460230001,-26.9532881422,0 -48.96929913370001,-26.953287988,0 -48.9693032007,-26.9532878153,0 -48.96930677819999,-26.9532876252,0 -48.9693098442,-26.9532874189,0 -48.9693123798,-26.9532871977,0 -48.9693143693,-26.9532869628,0 -48.96931580039999,-26.9532867158,0 -48.96931666449999,-26.9532864583,0 -48.969316956,-26.9532861916,0 
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Ground</name>
                <LookAt>
                    <longitude>-48.9692241831</longitude>
                    <latitude>-26.9532849988</latitude>
                    <altitude>0</altitude>
                    <heading>-0.8219678042850001</heading>
                    <tilt>68</tilt>
                    <range>18.4258281664</range>
                </LookAt>
                <styleUrl>#ground_path_#ff0000</styleUrl>
                <LineString>
                    <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                    <coordinates>
                        -48.969316956,-26.9532861916,0 -48.96913141020001,-26.9532838059,0 
                    </coordinates>
                </LineString>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark id="end_174725776">
                <name>ERB Gasparinho - ST01 - MPO</name>
                <description><![CDATA[<b>Product:</b> PTP58600<br>
                          <b>Pointing at:</b> <a href="#end_174725968">EGO - LAN - Jurema</a><br>
                          <b>Profile:</b> 0.0 kilometers, Line-of-Sight<br>
                          <b>Antenna:</b> Cambium Networks Integrated Dual Polar Antenna<br>
                          <b>Antenna height:</b> 10.0 m<br>
                          <b>Description:</b> <br>
                                  <img src="http://profile.heywhatsthat.com/bin/profile.cgi?src=MTPTP&metric=1&axes=1&curvature=1&pt1=-26.9532838059%2C-48.9691314102%2C%2C%2C&pt0=-26.9532861916%2C-48.969316956%2C%2C%2C"><br>


            <em>
                Profile images are Copyright 2008 Michael Kosowsky.
                All rights reserved. Used with permission. For more
                information, visit
                <a href="http://www.heywhatsthat.com/">HeyWhatsThat</a>
                </em>]]></description>
                <LookAt>
                    <longitude>-48.969316956</longitude>
                    <latitude>-26.9532861916</latitude>
                    <altitude>10</altitude>
                    <heading>85.1780321957</heading>
                    <tilt>68</tilt>
                    <range>101.842582817</range>
                </LookAt>
                <styleUrl>#antenna</styleUrl>
                <Point>
                    <extrude>1</extrude>
                    <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
                    <coordinates>-48.969316956,-26.9532861916,9.999999999999998</coordinates>
                </Point>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark id="end_174725968">
                <name>EGO - LAN - Jurema</name>
                <description><![CDATA[<b>Product:</b> PTP58600<br>
                          <b>Pointing at:</b> <a href="#end_174725776">ERB Gasparinho - ST01 - MPO</a><br>
                          <b>Profile:</b> 0.0 kilometers, Line-of-Sight<br>
                          <b>Antenna:</b> Cambium Networks Integrated Dual Polar Antenna<br>
                          <b>Antenna height:</b> 10.0 m<br>
                          <b>Description:</b> <br>
                                  <img src="http://profile.heywhatsthat.com/bin/profile.cgi?src=MTPTP&metric=1&axes=1&curvature=1&pt1=-26.9532861916%2C-48.969316956%2C%2C%2C&pt0=-26.9532838059%2C-48.9691314102%2C%2C%2C"><br>


            <em>
                Profile images are Copyright 2008 Michael Kosowsky.
                All rights reserved. Used with permission. For more
                information, visit
                <a href="http://www.heywhatsthat.com/">HeyWhatsThat</a>
                </em>]]></description>
                <LookAt>
                    <longitude>-48.9691314102</longitude>
                    <latitude>-26.9532838059</latitude>
                    <altitude>10</altitude>
                    <heading>265.177948095</heading>
                    <tilt>68</tilt>
                    <range>101.842582817</range>
                </LookAt>
                <styleUrl>#antenna</styleUrl>
                <Point>
                    <extrude>1</extrude>
                    <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
                    <coordinates>-48.96913141020001,-26.9532838059,9.999999999999998</coordinates>
                </Point>
            </Placemark>
            <Folder>
                <name>Ticks</name>
            </Folder>
        </Folder>
    </Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because this XML has default namespace `xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"`.

```
System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsManager = new System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);

xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2");

foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("ns:kml/ns:Document/ns:Folder"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed as requested and returns the error:

```
Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.
```

Code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    var xml = client.DownloadString(Server.MapPath("doc.xml"));
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsManager = new System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2");

    foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("ns:kml/ns:Document/ns:Folder"))
    {
        string teste = node.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
        foreach (XmlNode node1 in node.SelectNodes("Placemark"))
        {
            string teste1 = node.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```